# Magento 2 - Edit Invoice PDF in a custom theme

Tags: magento2

I want to edit the printable PDF invoice in Magento 2. To do this, I need to edit:

```
vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Pdf/AbstractPdf.php
```

But, what is the path I need so it does not get overridden during upgrade. I know the path should be something like this (but i cant figure it out):

```
/app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Sales/ ? / ? / AbstractPdf.php
```

With templates, I know the path is /template/...but this is a Model - so Im not sure I know how that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path is the same as is in module-sales, so: `/app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/AbstractPdf.php`
is where to put it.